# Why is LaTeX adding a newline when trying to create a table within a table?

Tags: tables

I have this LaTeX code:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
$h_{fe} = 70$     &  $h_{fe} = 170$ & $h_{fe} = 250$ \\
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
     & \textbf{Calc.} & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{\% Diff.}  \\
$I_{C}$     & 1.838 & 1.780 &  3.15 \\
$V_{B}$ & 2.975& 2.992 & 0.57 \\
$V_{C}$ & 6.692& 6.796 & 1.55\\
$V_{E}$ & 2.210& 2.203& 0.32\\
\end{tabular}     &
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\textbf{Calc.}  & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{Diff} \\
     &
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
\textbf{Calc.}  & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{Diff} \\
     &
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
```

The output is:

[image]

How do I stop LaTeX from adding a leaving space at the top of the 2nd and 3rd columns?

Comment: Re *"... leaving space ..."*: Do you mean *"leading space"*? Or *"trailing space"*? Or something else?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to nest tabulars in the first place: use `\multicolumn` for spanning several columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$h_{fe} = 70$}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$h_{fe} = 170$}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{$h_{fe} = 250$} \\
 & \textbf{Calc.} & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{\% Diff.}
 & \textbf{Calc.} & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{\% Diff.}
 & \textbf{Calc.} & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{\% Diff.} \\
$I_{C}$ & 1.838 & 1.780 & 3.15 & & & & & & \\
$V_{B}$ & 2.975 & 2.992 & 0.57 & & & & & & \\
$V_{C}$ & 6.692 & 6.796 & 1.55 & & & & & & \\
$V_{E}$ & 2.210 & 2.203 & 0.32 & & & & & & \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different realization that saves space and avoids the vertical rules. You can explain in the caption what “C”, “S” and “\% D” mean.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  *{3}{S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=1.3] S[table-format=1.2]}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$h_{\mathrm{fe}} = 70$}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$h_{\mathrm{fe}} = 170$}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$h_{\mathrm{fe}} = 250$} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
 & {C} & {S} & {\% D} & {C} & {S} & {\% D} & {C} & {S} & {\% D} \\
\midrule
$I_{C}$ & 1.838 & 1.780 & 3.15 & 1.111 & 2.222 & 3.3 & 4.444 & 5.555 & 6.6 \\
$V_{B}$ & 2.975 & 2.992 & 0.57 & & & & & & \\
$V_{C}$ & 6.692 & 6.796 & 1.55 & & & & & & \\
$V_{E}$ & 2.210 & 2.203 & 0.32 & & & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Top-align `[t]` all the inner `tabular`s.  By default, `tabular` is vertically center-aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
$h_{fe} = 70$     &  $h_{fe} = 170$ & $h_{fe} = 250$ \\
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c|c}
     & \textbf{Calc.} & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{\% Diff.}  \\
$I_{C}$     & 1.838 & 1.780 &  3.15 \\
$V_{B}$ & 2.975& 2.992 & 0.57 \\
$V_{C}$ & 6.692& 6.796 & 1.55\\
$V_{E}$ & 2.210& 2.203& 0.32\\
\end{tabular}     & 
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c}
\textbf{Calc.}  & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{Diff} \\
     & 
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c}
\textbf{Calc.}  & \textbf{Sim.} & \textbf{Diff} \\
     & 
\end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]